# Using c# with CefSharp and unity player with il2cpp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

So i have a browser game running with unity il2cpp on the browser opened with CefSharp. Any idea on how to automate simple tasks of the game? like moving the player or stuff like that. I do have methods used by the client but im missing the use of it inside the player in cefsharp.

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: So you've got a website loaded in CefSharp and you want to send mouse or keyboard events to the browser?

Comment: yes but in the browser there is a client of a game written in unity il2cpp... is there anyway to interact with that client? i mean not sending kbm input but using the methods of the client, to automate stuff

Comment: What does 'in the browser there is a client of a game written in unity il2cpp' mean exactly? How does CefSharp fit in exactly?

Comment: that this type of browser multiplayer games are written in unity il2cpp and you have the client in the browser